# How do you load docker-selenium chrome standalone in azure container service?

Tags: azure, docker, containers

According to the github readme (https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium) the chrome standalone needs the option "-v /dev/shm:/dev/shm" but I am struggling to find in the documentation how to do this correctly.

The full docker run command looks like this:

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/standalone-chrome:3.12.0-cobalt
```

My reason for needing this is I have tests that specifically fail due to not having this option enabled.

Currently my azure command looks like this:

```
az container create --resource-group ${resourceGroup} --name ${containerName} --image selenium/standalone-chrome:3.12.0-cobalt --dns-name-label ${dnsNameLabel} --ports 4444
```

I have been trying to play around with the --azure-file-volume options with no success. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit:

Until this is figured out I have decided to use azure vms. Using a vm image that has docker installed and starts up the docker-selenium container. It is not quite as fast or as pretty to script but it gets the job done without having the issue with options to start a docker container with. For anyone that decides to go this route here is my cloud-init code for the vm.

```
#cloud-config
package_upgrade: true
package_reboot_if_required: true
runcmd:
- apt-get update
- curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
- curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
- sudo docker run -d -p 4444:4444 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm selenium/standalone-chrome:3.12.0-cobalt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there isn't a way to use Azure CLI to do this, you can use an Azure Resource Manager Template deployment.

Create a deployment template file, for example:
`selenium-aci-standalone-example.json`

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "dnsNameLabel": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "name": "[parameters('dnsNameLabel')]",
            "properties": {
                "containers": [
                    {
                        "name": "standalone-chrome",
                        "properties": {
                            "image": "selenium/standalone-chrome",
                            "ports": [{ "port": "4444", "protocol": "TCP" }],
                            "resources": { "requests": { "cpu": "1.0", "memoryInGb": "1.5" } },
                            "volumeMounts": [{"name": "devshm", "mountPath": "/dev/shm"}]
                        }                        
                    }
                ],
                "ipAddress": {
                    "ports": [{ "port": "4444", "protocol": "TCP" }],
                    "type": "Public",
                    "dnsNameLabel": "[parameters('dnsNameLabel')]"
                },
                "osType": "Linux",
                "volumes": [
                    {
                        "name": "devshm",
                        "emptyDir": {}
                    }
                ]
            },
            "type": "Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then you can execute the deployment with Azure CLI:

```
az group create -n selenium-standalone-rg -l westus2
az group deployment create -g selenium-standalone-rg --template-file .\selenium-aci-standalone-example.json --parameters dnsNameLabel=test-standalone-selenium-chrome
```

Mounting an `emptyDir` to `/dev/shm` on the node containers solved this issue for us running Selenium Grid with Azure Container Instances. It seems that it's not possible to directly control the size of the volume - and I couldn't find information about the size of an emptyDir volume in ACI documentation - but all the broken pipe errors went away in our test runs after we added the volume configuration to our ARM template.